# Order of additional screenshots when submitting app in iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I'm currently submitting my app for review and I've uploaded the main screenshot, but am unsure of how to get my additional screenshots to appear in the correct order. You have to select them all before uploading and there's no indication of what order they will be in!

Can someone let me know whether you need to select the screenshots in correct or reverse order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add them in reverse order.

So if the main screen shot is ss1.jpg

add the others in this order
ss4.jpg
ss3.jpg
ss2.jpg

Then hit the upload button

Hope this helps

Comment: Great, thanks Mick! It's so un-intuative, very strange for apple! Now the app review process begins... :S

Comment: Good luck. I am currently working on the 7th revision to my application.
I do not understand why apple can not simply give a concise list of what the issues with the application are, rather than finding a single issue, rejecting the application, then making you go through the whole review process again, only to find there is another issue. And so the process begins again :(

Comment: That's terrible, must be a nightmare! Such a bad system. Good luck with this revision!

Comment: It's so confusing -- I was trying to figure out just what order the screenshot upload form required but couldn't figure it out. I finally figured "inputting them in the correct order can't be wrong, so many people are likely to do that". Turned out it was wrong -- Apple reversed the order, and now I have troubles changing it back for my localization.

Answer (score 2):

People should know that this post is very outdated. iTunes Connect now lets you drag and drop images in whatever order you like, and Apple doesn't reverse anything.

Answer (score 1):

Mick is 100% correct. It boggled us at first too (keep in mind iTunes Connect is slow so having to upload it again was a drag...)