# Editing screenshots in iTunes Connect after iOS app was approved

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

In the iTunes Connect App Management interface -- how do I edit the screenshots for my localized (approved and live) iPhone app?

Unfortunately, the web upload form had a bug which actually required the screenshots to be provided in reverse order (I provided them in the correct order, which meant that Apple reversed them and now they ended up wrong). [Also mentioned here at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914875/order-of-additional-screenshots-when-submitting-app-in-itunes-connect). I only managed to edit the 4 screenshots in the US version, but not my localized version, and that was in the old interface.

Comment: PS: I should mention that I contacted iTunes Connect Support over this, and their first reply to me was showing me a table of editable states of the app -- apparently, my app is in no such editbale state (and it's successfully approved), and it seems that table suggests I can't edit screenshots now. They referred me to Appendix A of this PDF (http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf). I asked them again and hope for more info.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Apple support now got back with the (somehow not too satisfactory) answer:

> If your app is currently for sale on
>   the App Store, you will need to submit
>   an update in order to change your app
>   screenshots.
>
> If you have any further questions
>   regarding this, please let us know.

Comment: This is very bad. I just realized 2 of my screenshots show a small black mouse arrow on them. Pretty hard to see since the screens are mostly black, which is why I missed it the last 30 times I looked at those images. Still, I don't want to update my app just to fix Screenshots, that's sort of insane.

Comment: Acutally new version of Developer Guide has an update from Sept 2010: Screenshots are now an unlocked metadata attribute and can be updated at any time

Comment: With the new update of iTunesConnect, is it still possible ? Because personnaly I can't.

Comment: No, as of January 2013, Apple has reversed its policy yet again, and screenshots are locked once the App version is approved.

Answer (score 114):

The current standing on this has changed to:

> Beginning January 9 [2013], app screenshots will be locked in iTunes Connect once your app has been approved. New screenshots may be uploaded when you submit a binary for an update to an existing app or a new app.

Comment: I really don't understand this.  The screenshots are quite important and sometimes you upload something that might have an error / issue.  Why can we not just update our app's metadata without having to upload an entire new binary??

Comment: I think it's so the approval process is fair and airtight. For example, if metadata updates were allowed then some developers could post inappropriate images or change the keyword tags constantly to boost their SEO (e.g. add "Valentine's" near Feb 14th). It's annoying, but I often upload the binary and then add the images a few days later while I wait for approval.

Comment: I think this is fairly reasonable to not be allowed to change the images themselves, but changing the order could still be allowed, which is all that the OP (or myself) want. Still, I can understand that it's a more coherent policy to just not allow editing of metadata outside of an update.

Comment: It's actually been a long running issue with scammers who've been putting up fake screenshots and app icons after their apps have been approved e.g. - http://gizmodo.com/5970489/apple-let-a-hilariously-fake-halo-4-into-the-app-store, http://www.phonearena.com/news/Apple-allows-two-fake-Halo-4-apps-to-be-sold-in-the-App-Store_id37984.

Ideally they'd have a way to just re-submit the screenshots for approval though I think if you're resubmitting screenshots you might as well resubmit the whole app

Comment: @jklp Many companies pay outside firms huge sums of money for each of these releases. Having these restrictions on metadata puts undue stress on the (non-Apple) approval process for these apps. Agile is out the window. When a mistake goes out it's like you have printed an entire issue of Time Magazine incorrectly and someone's head has to roll for it. It shouldn't be that way. The web industry hasn't been that way for 2 decades. iOS has taken us back to the days of "burning the gold master".

Answer (score 6):

I was able to change my screenshots after my app was ready for sale, just click on "View Details" in iTunes Connect, delete the old screenshots and replace them, then "Done". The change is not instant so wait a bit. Then you will see your new screenshots on AppStore ;)

Comment: Can you please elaborate where can we find the option View Details. I have to change the screenshots urgently, we cant wait to upload another version.

Comment: This answer is outdated.

Answer (score 5):

As of today, it appears you can't edit screenshots after you submit a new version. I tried everything but couldn't delete the draft screenshots until I finally removed my app from submission.

I usually use the time after submission to edit and improve the screenshots, but now have to be doing it before submission. This is a horrible change. Here is the email from support.

> Being unable to now edit screenshots while an app is in "Waiting for
>   Review" status, is expected behavior.
>
> Developer-facing documentation currently lists "Waiting for Review" as
>   a state where locked metadata can be edited. Screenshots should be the
>   only locked metadata that cannot be edited while an app is in the
>   "Waiting for Review" status.
>
> We are currently updating the developer resources and documentation to
>   clarify

Answer (score 4):

From the updated manual :
(*)

> If you have new application screenshots for a version of your application, it is best to wait until this new version of your app is approved before updating your screenshots in iTunes Connect. Updating these before a version approval will change the screenshots for the currently-live application version. This best practice also applies to application metadata changes that you wish to coordinate for a specific version.

On the other hand, in the table in Appendix A it is stated that the screenshots are Locked, Version-level (page 153).

Version-level is:

> If the item is marked on the Version, then the item information will relate to a specific version and may vary between versions.

Locked is:

> If the item is marked as Locked, it can only be edited in an Editable State.

And a list of Editable states is:
Prepare For Upload, Waiting For Upload, Waiting For Review, Waiting For Export Compliance, Upload Received, Rejected, Developer Rejected, Invalid Binary, Missing Screenshot.

None of these states can be reached once the app is Ready For Sale by using any button in the iTunes Connect. The only reasonable thing that I can think of is submitting another minor version binary to Apple and looking for the possibility of changing the screenshots during the submission process.
The problem is (*):

> If you have new application screenshots for a version of your application, it is best to wait until this new version of your app is approved before updating your screenshots in iTunes Connect.

So how do I do it correctly????????

Comment: The first paragraph is incorrect, then. From my experience, you can't edit the screenshots (or icon file) after the app has been approved and is Ready for Sale. The new iTunes Connect lets you upload a different set of screenshots just for the new version without affecting the current version in the App Store.

Comment: Agreed, though this seems to be a recent change.

Answer (score 3):

I thought the same exact thing a couple of days ago. Then I uploaded it again in reverse order but instead it was random. They need to make a better UI for this. One where we dont even need to re-upload them, but arrows to move it up/down.

Answer (score 3):

The official answer I received from Apple is:

> Your app screenshots cannot be edited once your app has been approved. You can edit them in all other editable states.
>
> Please note, when updating your app currently, you will be able to provide new screenshots and the new screenshots will not go live until the update is approved.
>
> If you have any further questions regarding this, please let us know.

Answer (score 2):

There's been some back and forth on the possibility of changing screenshots of an app that is in "Ready for Sale" state, without having to upload new binary.
At one point it was possible, but as of January 9th 2013 it requires a new binary:

> Beginning January 9, app screenshots will be locked in iTunes Connect
>   once your app has been approved. New screenshots may be uploaded when
>   you submit a binary for an update to an existing app or a new app. For
>   more information on capturing and using screenshots, read the Xcode
>   User Guide.

source: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=1092013a

Answer (score 1):

Images CAN be edited after an app is available for sale. This was changed at end of 2010. If you already have 5 images - the upload link will not work until you delete one. No need to worry - if you delete one and have any issues on the DPI or RGB of what you are trying to upload (get an error or it is rejected) you can always click 'cancel' rather than 'save' and your original images will remain.

Comment: This is not correct; apps in a state of 'For Sale' cannot have their screenshots changed. To change them, a new version must be started (and ultimately released).

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add new version. Just wait about 1hr and your changes at screenshot gallery will appear at AppStore.

Answer (score -1):

Solution for me was to use Safari. The controls would not show in Google Chrome. Using Safari I could modify the metadata.