# Uploading new screenshots to iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, app-store, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editing screenshots in iTunes Connect after iPhone app was approved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368555/editing-screenshots-in-itunes-connect-after-iphone-app-was-approved)

I've recently uploaded an update for one of my iPhone apps, but I didn't update the screenshots. It has now dawned on me that they are old screens for the new game, which might be confusing for users.

Is there anyway to upload the new screenshots without submitting a new binary?

Thanks
James

Comment: Nice quick closure by the mods there. Only took them 1 & 1/2 years!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like Apple can't make up their mind what they want to allow.  Originally, you couldn't and then they changed it to allow you to change them and now you can't change them anymore.

Here's the [relevant section of the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW1):

> Important: Screenshots are locked for all apps except Newsstand apps.
>   Newsstand apps are able to change their screenshots without creating a
>   new version of the app.

Comment: Ah Thanks. That's a shame, I hope my review doesn't get rejected because I didn't update them!

Comment: You can always reject the binary and submit them.  It just resets your position in the review queue.  Your review won't get rejected if you didn't update them, it'll just be confusing to users.  I think they just did this to try and get rid of all the scam products (hopefully)

Comment: You can update screenshots without submitting a new binary. Click the edit button next the App Localizations within iTunes Connect.

Comment: @crooksy88 This answer is 1.5 yrs old and was correct at the time of posting.  Instead of lazily downvoting it, how about editing it so that other people finding it in the future will have the corrected version?

Comment: Sorry about that fella. It wasn't personal.

Comment: @crooksy88 I think you missed the point.

Comment: @iWasRobbed Link is broken, and i can't edit since I don t know where it used to lead.

Answer (score 5):

Wait a sec, update Sept 16, 2010:

**Screenshots are now an unlocked metadata attribute and can be updated at any time**

From the iTunes Connect Developer Guide.

Although when I go into iTunes connect and click the Edit link to edit my Screenshots, I see that I can change the order of them but I don't see an upload button. I also see I can click an "X" at the top right of the screenshot. I assume this deletes it, but will I then get a box to add one back?? Not really sure I want to experiment here. So much for intuitive interfaces.

Comment: Yes, now, you can change your screenshots when you wish. Last time I tried there was a button to add them back, it might not show if you have 5 screenshots already?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like Apple's documentation doesn't match their implementation. I agree that iTunesConnect does not allow us to edit the large 512x512 icon (that's the case today anyway, 08.03.2011). But according to the iTunesConnect_DevelopmentGuide.pdf (version 6.9, July 20, 2011, p.97), "Clicking on the Edit button next to Uploads will allow you to edit the large app icon and your screenshots for your version. For Mac OS X apps, you will only be able to edit the screenshots, as the large icon is uploaded as part of the binary".

Comment: For iOS, the Logo is uploaded in the Binary as a 57x57 or 114x114, and a 512x512 is uploaded through iTunes connect. Not sure if it still does, but I once uploaded an app with only a 57x57 included and it pulled the 512x512 down from iTunes (only on Retina display phones anyway).