# Updating App Store image for production iOS App

Tags: iphone, app-store

I released a new iPhone App recently, but once it appeared in the App Store following Apple's review, the App Store icon was surprisingly ugly; so I want to replace it right away.

However, whilst I'd expected to be able to do that through iTunesConnect or the Developer Portal, I haven't been able to find any way to revisit all the App meta data and screenshots etc. that I'd uploaded during the App ID registration phase.

My suspicion is that I may need to make this minor change to the App officially, as a version update; can anyone confirm this, or suggest how I should be replacing the App Store icon image quickly, please?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368555/editing-screenshots-in-itunes-connect-after-iphone-app-was-approved

Comment: Thank you, Chitra; see my reply to Ratikanta Patra below also.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news. Seems like you have to release an update for this purpose. [Check this link](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=1092013a)

It states

> Beginning January 9, app screenshots will be locked in iTunes Connect once your app has been approved. New screenshots may be uploaded when you submit a binary for an update to an existing app or a new app

Comment: Thanks for the info and link, Ratikanta; most posts related to this seem to talk about the screen shots in particular, and I can only find a slight mention of the App icon itself. However, in the context of this other reading (that limitations on screenshot alterations were a security measure from Apple), I'm inclined to think you're right, that I have to update the whole App to do this. I'll reply categorically as and when I can confirm this.