# iTunes Connect Screenshots Update

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

How long does Apple take to update Screenshots on iTunes even after the app has moved to **Ready for Sale**? I have already submitted the app and it has been approved. It is now more than 15 hrs later and the Screenshots and app are still not available.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368555/editing-screenshots-in-itunes-connect-after-iphone-app-was-approved

Comment: it will take more then a day to display your app in search.

Answer (score 1):

If you setup everything correctly. Make a minor change in version information and click save. Then it will be visible soon.

Answer (score 0):

The results will take more than a day to appear in search.