# How to rebuild iOS in EXPO?

Tags: ios, expo, rebuild

I want to update the screen shots and keywords of the app, but I don't know what to do. Is this correct?

### Expo Rebuilding Process

1) Update *version, buildNumber* in app.json file. (last version 1.0.0 >>> update 1.1.0)

2) Run *$ expo build:ios*

3) Deploying to App Stores.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "version": "1.1.0",
    ...
    "ios": {
      "buildNumber": "1.1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to change the screenshots and keywords, you have to login to 
[itunesconnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) website. Then follow these steps.

1. Select MyApps.
2. Select yourApp from the list.
3. Remove the screenshots you already uploaded.
4. Add your new screenshots.
5. Scroll down and you will see keywords. Remove the current and add the new one as well

Note : If you have not submitted the app yet, Please refer the [link](https://clearbridgemobile.com/how-to-submit-an-app-to-the-app-store/)

Comment: I know, but the 1.0.0 version has already been released and cannot be changed on the App Store connection.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9375441/7855724, You can delete the screenshots and upload the new ones. The changes are not instant. So you might have to give it some time. Hope this fixes your problem :)